# There is no ViewData item of type 'IEnumerable<SelectListItem>' that has the key 'ProjectBranch'

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I have tried suggestions from other answers but they didn't seem to work 
I have this in my controller

```
var BranchList = new List<String>();
var BranchQry = (from p in db.Projects
                 where p.Branch != null
                 orderby p.Branch
                 select new {
                     ID = p.Id,
                     Branch = p.Branch
                 }).Distinct().ToList();
//BranchList.AddRange(BranchQry.Distinct());
ViewBag.ProjectBranch = new SelectList(BranchQry, "ProjectBranch", "ProjectBranch");
```

And this in my view

```
@if (rolelist.Contains("readwrite") && rolelist.Contains("dataadmin"))
{                   
    <p>      
        @Html.DropDownList("ProjectBranch", (IEnumerable<SelectListItem>)ViewBag.ProjectBranch) 
        <input type="submit" value="Filter" /> 
    </p>         
}
```

Getting Error:

> There is no ViewData item of type 'IEnumerable' that
>   has the key 'ProjectBranch'

I changed it to this but still same error

```
var BranchList = new List<String>();
var BranchQry = from p in db.Projects
                where p.Branch != null
                orderby p.Branch
                select p.Branch;                               
BranchList.AddRange(BranchQry.Distinct());
ViewBag.ProjectBranch = new SelectList(BranchList, "ID", "Branch");
```

**EDITED:**

```
var BranchList = new List<String>();
var BranchQry = (from p in db.Projects
                 where p.Branch != null
                 orderby p.Branch
                 select new
                 {
                     ID = p.Id,
                     Branch = p.Branch
                 }).Distinct().ToList();                         
//BranchList.AddRange(BranchQry.Distinct());
ViewBag.ProjectBranchList = new SelectList(BranchQry, "ID", "Branch");
```

And in my view

```
@if (rolelist.Contains("readwrite") && rolelist.Contains("dataadmin"))
{                   
    <p>      
        @Html.DropDownList("ProjectBranch", (IEnumerable<SelectListItem>)ViewBag.ProjectBranchList)
        <input type="submit" value="Filter" /> 
    </p>         
}
```

Comment: You can't name the `ViewBag` property the same name as the property your binding to (assuming you model does have a property named `ProjectBranch`). And you also need to make sure you generate the `SelectList` again if you return the view.

Answer (score 2):

You are doing a number of things wrong here.  Fixing any one of them wouldn't solve your problem, so you have to fix all of them.

**First:**

```
 var BranchQry = (from p in db.Projects
                       where p.Branch != null
                       orderby p.Branch
                       select new {
                           ID = p.Id,
                           Branch = p.Branch
                       }).Distinct().ToList();
```

This creates a query which contains two elements, ID and Branch.  Then, you do this:

```
ViewBag.ProjectBranch = new SelectList BranchQry, "ProjectBranch", "ProjectBranch");
```

SelectList takes 3 parameters here, the fist is an IEnumerable, the second is the name of the property in your IEnumerable that represents the Value field of the SelectList, and the third is name of the property that represents the Text property.  These can be the same, but they must be a valid property in the IEnumerable.  You don't have a property called ProjectBranch in the IEnumerable, you only have ID and Branch.

Presumably, you want Value to be ID, and Branch to be Text so this should be:

```
ViewBag.ProjectBranch = new SelectList(BranchQry, "ID", "Branch");
```

**Second:**

You should never name your ViewBag property name the same as your other property names.  This confuses the model binder.

So change it to this:

```
ViewBag.ProjectBranchList = new SelectList(BranchQry, "ID", "Branch");
```

Then do this:

```
@Html.DropDownList("ProjectBranch", (IEnumerable<SelectListItem>)ViewBag.ProjectBranchList)
```

Although it's much better to use strongly typed models instead:

```
@Html.DropDownListFor(x => x.ProjectBranch, Model.ProjectBranchList)
```

Comment: I changed it but still get the same error. I am performing the query in the controller but my view has this
@model EHPortfolio.ViewModels.MyWork

Comment: @AyoFafore - you obviously did not "change it" correctly, because what I have written here will work if you have properly done so.  What's more, if you're using the strongly typed version I mention above, ViewData shouldn't be involved at all.  If the error is identical, still saying ProjectBranch, then the error is somewhere else if you changed the name to ProjectBranchList.

Comment: I have the same error. I am sure I changed it to what you have up there. @erik-funkenbusche

Comment: var BranchList = new List<String>();
               var BranchQry = (from p in db.Projects
                                where p.Branch != null
                                orderby p.Branch
                                select new
                                {
                                    ID = p.Id,
                                    Branch = p.Branch
                                }).Distinct().ToList();                         
               //BranchList.AddRange(BranchQry.Distinct());
               ViewBag.ProjectBranchList = new SelectList(BranchQry, "ID", "Branch");

Comment: @if (rolelist.Contains("readwrite") && rolelist.Contains("dataadmin"))
               {                   
                        <p>      
                @Html.DropDownList("ProjectBranch", (IEnumerable<SelectListItem>)ViewBag.ProjectBranchList)
                            <input type="submit" value="Filter" /> 
                            </p>         
               }

Comment: @AyoFafore - Don't post code in comments.  Edit your question.  I'm sorry, but it's impossible for this code to generate the error mentioned, as such the problem is in code somewhere else and you are misinterpreting where the error is coming from.

Comment: @AyoFafore - And i'm telling you, it's impossible for the code you've posted to be giving that error, therefore the error is somewhere else, in code you are not showing us, and you are misinterpreting something.

Comment: could this be the problem? @model EHPortfolio.ViewModels.MyWork

Comment: @AyoFafore - Your model has nothing to do with ViewData.  This is the point that illustrates that the problem is somewhere else.  We've changed all ViewData references to no longer use ProjectBranch, thus if the error is still saying that... then it's *different code* that is generating the error.

Comment: Problem I was having is that it is a null value.